# How to get proxy from PAC file using powershell?

Tags: powershell, proxy, pac

My company administrators have setup our machines to get proxy settings from a .pac file. The .pac file is complex and the proxy to use for a URL changes occasionally.

I often need to write powershell scripts that run tools that originate from linux e.g. git, pip, etc. These tools do not understand .pac files and don't use the normal windows network stack. I normally know which URLs these tools need to access and they tend to have a --proxy command line option that can be set.

My question is given a url is there any way to convert that into the correct proxy address that I can then pass to the tool I want to use? I can do this manually by reading the .pac file, but I'd like to script it.

Comment: A quick google search for `proxy pac parser` gives lots and lots of solutions for this.